# Can't connect to USB to Serial Device For Chrome Extension App

Tags: google-chrome-extension, serial-port, usb

I am currently getting an error about not being able to connect to my device through Chrome. I have the below code and allow for usb and serial in my manifest file.

```
var onGetDevices = function(ports) {
  for (var i=0; i<ports.length; i++) {
   console.log(ports[i].path);
   //connect to serial port
}
  chrome.serial.connect("/dev/tty.usbmodem1421", {bitrate: 9600}, onConnect);
};

var onConnect = function(connectionInfo) {
  // The serial port has been opened. Save its id to use later.
  console.log(connectionInfo);
};

 $( document ).ready(function() {
chrome.serial.getDevices(onGetDevices);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not add the correct permissions to my manifest file. I needed to add...

"usbDevices": [
      {
        "vendorId": "xxxx",
        "productId": 1234
      }
    ]
  }
]